# Adding image and text to Vue Select dropdown

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to make dropdowns with text and a picture. I wrote the code as written in the manual, here is the link https://vue-select.org/guide/slots.html

Help me please.

```
<v-select :options="options" label="title">
    <template slot="option" slot-scope="option">
        <img :src="option.cardImage">
        {{ option.title }}
    </template>
</v-select>



options: [{
    title: "country1",
    cardImage: "images/flag-20.png"

},
{
    title: "country2",
    cardImage: "images/flag``-21.png"

}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the locations of cardImage are not right. check this:

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    options: [{
    title: "country1",
    cardImage: "https://via.placeholder.com/20"

},
{
    title: "country2",
    cardImage: "https://via.placeholder.com/20"

}
]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@3.0.2"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-select :options="options" label="title">
    <template slot="option" slot-scope="option">
        <img :src="option.cardImage">
        {{ option.title }}
    </template>
  </v-select>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks you!

I have not added this code:
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@3.0.2"></script>

If you write like this, it also works.
cardImage: "images/flag-20.png"

Comment: I'm new to vue.js. Sorry for the dumb questions. How did you know that you need to add these links?
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@3.0.2"></script>

Can you tell me? Where can I see it?

Comment: vue-select is an external package. In vue js, when you have to use an external package, you have to install it and import it in your code. Here i am not directly installing vue-select, but added the link where the package is remotely hosted. But in your vue js project, you should install it and import it. I suggest you to read the documentations of both vue js and vue-select.